# OpenSSH hangs after login without showing login prompt

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, openssh, telnet

I ran across an issue with **ssh** after fresh Ubuntu 13.10 installation on Lenovo T420. I tried `git pull` (which failed) and this led me to more general **ssh** failing.

After spending some 2-3 hrs of beautiful Sunday morning I have established:

1. ssh is able to authenticate. see the log below. Also `telnet google.com 80` hangs on connecting.
2. I can connect using `putty` - it shows motd and prompt
3. It doesn't work on both wired and wireless connections, also I tried cellular network.
4. I can successfully login to localhost

here be the log:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to web1.mydevil.net (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = pl_PL.UTF-8
```

and then just keeps sending

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
```

without showing me the prompt and eventually disconnects.

I found out that `telnet google.com 80` hangs on `Connecting <IP-addr>...` as well.

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/auth.log` on the server for possible error messages?

Comment: Permission denied. as expected.
this is not my machine.

Comment: Hmm... is it possible that the server is somehow misconfigured? I'm not really sure how to debug this further. You could check the output of `ssh -vvv` if there's anything more interesting in the debug messages, but the client side log was rarely helpful for me when debugging issues like these.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this on turned out to be WTF LOL squared...

I got a hint that it was most likely **[ICMP packets being filtered](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2015/05/15/pmtud/)** by the firewall. So when you stumble upon this issue check it out.

In the article I found on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9555057) one reads:

```
ssh did not work. It would connect, flip some data back and forth (as shown with -v) and then would hang.

Certain websites would become inaccessible.
```

Which were my symptomps that appeared after switching my wireless router to another device. Device in question was Linksys WRT-54G running dd-wrt.

Comment: "Filter all ICMP and watch the world burn", indeed.  I take it DD-WRT was the failing device, right?

Comment: yup, that seemed to be the problem. Maybe I messed something with its configuration. It worked on another device running dd-wrt.